# While loop doesn't stop even if the variables match

Tags: python

The problem is that the loop doesn't stop even though the input is the same as the integer `secret_word` and I tried to convert it to an integer.

```
import random

a = [*range(0, 21)]
secret_word = random.choice(a)
print(secret_word)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 5
out_of_guesses = False
guess = ""

while guess != secret_word and not out_of_guesses:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = input("Vilket nummer väljer du 0 - 20 ")
        guess_count += 1
        try:
            int(guess)
        except ValueError:
            print("Ett fucing number dumbass")
    else:
        out_of_guesses = True

if out_of_guesses:
    print("Inga fler gissningar")
else:
    print("DAMN DU VANN")
```

Comment: `a = [*range(0, 21)]` is a confusing way of saying `a = list(range(21))`

Comment: a good tool to master is the debugger or some print statements that show the value of variables

Answer (score 3):

You correctly identified that the loop does not stop because `guess` is a string and `secret_word` is an integer, so that `guess != secret_word` is always true, and tried to convert `guess` to an integer.

But `int(guess)` does not change the value of `guess`, it creates a new value.

If you want to change `guess` to have this new value, you need to re-assign it:

```
guess = int(guess)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Change `int(guess)` into `guess = int(guess)`.

**Long Answer:**

It appears that in the line where you used `int(guess)`, you assumed that it would change the value of `guess` to the parsed int. The fact is that `int()` is a function that returns the parsed value, and it wouldn't change the value stored in `guess`. So if you need to re-assgin the returned int value to `guess` after calling `int()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

The input is taken as a string, not an integer. Just do :

```
guess = int(input("Vilket nummer väljer du 0 - 20 "))
```

Edit: Move it into the try loop too.

```
try:
  guess = int(input("Vilket nummer väljer du 0 - 20 "))
  guess_count += 1
except ValueError:
  print("Ett fucing number dumbass")
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but if the user puts a letter the program krashes is there any way i can do so that doesent happen?

Comment: Just move the code into the try loop. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the program a bit. Less variables is less possibility of errors.

```
import random

secret_word = random.choice(range(21))
print(secret_word)
guess_count = 5

while guess_count > 0:
    try:
        guess = int(input("Vilket nummer väljer du 0 - 20 "))
        if guess == secret_word:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Ett fucing number dumbass")
    guess_count -= 1

if guess_count == 0:
    print("Inga fler gissningar")
else:
    print("DAMN DU VANN")
```